# How to look into a column after making a graph from a bar plot?

Tags: r

So I made the graph "Most popular age group" and I found out that the age '26-35' is the most popular and now I am trying to look into what 'gender' they are comprised of and make another bar plot out of it.

```
filename <- read.csv("./XYZ.csv")
myData = filename

install.packages("ggplot")
library(ggplot2)


table(myData$Age)
barplot(table(myData$Age),xlab="Age group", ylab = 'Number of Purchases', main ='Most popular age group', col = 'pink',)
```

[image: graph of Most Popular Age group]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by adding the data, e.g. with ´dput(myData)´. See also [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: I think you need a stacked barplot... You need do count not only by age but also gender... try maybe to include gender in your call to table()

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  count(Age, Gender) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Age, y = n, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", color="black")
```

Here I am using ggplot2 and dplyr, if you want to use barplot() maybe look here: https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html